# Using an array in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I want to use array in condition if for my program, but I am having problems implementing it.

I have an array :

```
//I want to put my condition in array column 3 (in title)
Data[] hotel = {
        new Data(-6.8851995, 108.4978142, "Grage Sangkan Hotel & Spa",
                "Jl. Raya Sangkanhurip No.1 Desa Sangkanhurip"),
        new Data(-6.879592, 108.513353, "Prima Hotel Sangkanhurip ",
                "Jl. Panawuwan No.121 Kec. Cigandamekar "),
        new Data(-6.883889, 108.500000, "Tirta Sanita Spa Resort ",
                "Jl.Panawuwan No.98 Kec.Cigandamekar")
}
```

and I have a condition:

```
//my condition equals array column 3 (in title)
if (v.getTitle().equals(hotel[3] ? ??)){  // in here I don't know what can I do 
    tempat = new Intent(Peta.this, KetWisata.class);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getTitle().contains("Wisata Cibulan")) {
        tampil = "wis_cibulan";
    }
    if (v.getTitle().contains("Linggarjati Indah")) {
        tampil = "wis_linggarjati";
    }
    if (v.getTitle().contains("Balong Dalem")) {
        tampil = "wis_balongdalem";
    }
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You want to get the title of the third element of your array ? Can you show the code of the Data class ?

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you use `v.getTitle()` to get the title element out of `v`, you need to use a similar method to get the title value out of the Data element in your array.

Assuming `v` is also of type `Data` then the code you ask for is...

```
if ( v.getTitle().equals( hotel[3].getTitle() )) {
    // Your code                  -----------
}
```

That way you're testing whether the two titles are equal to one another. Just treat hotel[3] as if it is any other variable of type `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, **arrays are zero-based.**  An array of length 3 has a maximum indexable element of 2 - anything higher and you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Second, this line:

```
if (v.getTitle().equals(hotel[3] ? ??)
```

is incorrect, and wouldn't work even if the question marks weren't present.  The reason being:
  `hotel` has a type of `Data`, and we can only presume that `getTitle()` returns a `String`.   You can't compare `String` to `Data`.

What you want instead is something like this:

```
if (v.getTitle().equals(hotel[2].getTitle())
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay You Can Create A Void something Like That:

```
class RandomStuffs {
public void ArrayEquals(ArrayList Array , string SearchData){
int I = 0;
int T = 0;
Boolean Continue = false;
for(I = 0;I < Array.length ; I ++){
for(T = 0;T <Array[i].length;T ++){
if(Array[I][T] == SearchData ){
Continue = true;
break;
}
}
if(Continue == true){
return true;
}else {
return false;
}
}
}
```

And Called it like  that:

```
Class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){
RandomStuffs Class = new RandomStuffs();
if(Class.ArrayEquals(hotel , "Wisata Subilian"){
//Code To Execute
}else {
//Error Handler Or Another Block
}
}
}
```

This Loop Check If The Multidimensional Array Contains a string
If this wasn't what you want Then You Could Play A little Bit with the loop and it will rightly work out. 
Or Just Tell Me And I will Answer you 
Between Your Question Isn't Clear you didn't really specified what you nees